# Java get changed title of a dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, swt, title

I am trying to catch SWT events, like SWT.activate, SWT.deactivate and SWT.dispose in Eclipse. So, I can see which dialog was opened or activated, which was closed and which was deactivated. If the event was caught, I extract the Shell object and extracts its title with `shell.getText()`. To listen to events, I used an untyped listener (edited):

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.Activate, shellListener);
Listener shellListener = new Listener(){
    @Override public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        if (event.widget.getClass() == org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.class){
            Shell shell = (Shell) e.widget;
            String shellTitle = shell.getText();
            if (event.type == Activate) {
                String message = "The following dialog was activated: " + shellTitle;
                // do other stuff with 'message'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

If in Eclipse I open 'New' and the listener above correctly displays 'New' as activated dialog. But if I select 'Java Interface' within the 'New' dialog, then I am landing in a dialog, called 'New Java Interface'. But my `handleEvent` method is not fired and therefore I cannot extract the new dialog title. My question is: What kind of event is called or what happens, when I am in an Eclipse dialog and clicking on something in it which leads me to another dialog (with a new title)?

Comment: The Eclipse dialogs use SWT shells and fire the usual shell events. How are you setting up the listeners?

Comment: I am writing `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.Activate, shellListener)` and the shellListener is something like `Listener shellListener = new Listener(){ @Override public void handleEvent(Event e) {//do stuff}};` In the do stuff block, I am getting the Shell object and its text. But as described in the case above, if the title changes within a dialog, no event is thrown (or I am missing something).

Comment: Edit your post add this code in post.

Comment: Ok, I did it. I added the code block so that everyone can see more of my code. I unfortunately cannot poste my whole code, since it is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here comes from the fact that the New 'dialog' in Eclipse is actually a **Wizard**. When you select 'Java Interface' (in the 'New' dialog) you are actually then landing not in another dialog but on a page within the same wizard. **Every page** in this wizard can have it's own **title** but behind the scene it is the same underlying shell object, that is why you don't receive further events.

By the way: when working with the `SWT.Activate`, `SWT.Deactivate` and other similar shell events, it might be helpflul / easier to the a [ShellAdapter](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/ShellAdapter.html)

Comment: You're right. The normal untyped listeners were the first listeners I learned. I newly figured out that there are also special listeners. Regarding the wizard thing: You said that it is the same shell object, but a wizard in it. How can I retrieve this wizard? And what kind of event is it when a page in a wizard is changed? Perhaphs I can just add a listener to it.